# How to distinguish one mobile device from another by HTTP request

Tags: session, session-cookies

I have a web application that is accessed from mobile devices. I need to detect that some requests are made from one device while others from another. I don't necessarily need to know the unique device id or something like that, I just need to distinguish one device from another. I thought about using IP address, but I'm afraid that some carriers might have similar IPs for all devices in some region. Is there a common way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's usually done with cookies with unique identifiers (session ID for example)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Do you know whether or not all mobile device browsers accept cookies?

Comment: They all accept cookies, yes. It's the standard nowadays for session persistence. Users used to disable cookies in the past, but if you find someone still doing such paranoid thing, you can be assured that he already knows it's going to mess most of his web experience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normaly wap gateways has few IP in each region. You can use cookies although it could cause some problems because many wap gateways doesn´t support. So you can use URL session ID.

Some carriers include in HTTP headers unique ID ([some info](http://certificateerror.blogspot.com/search?q=operators+http)). You should investigate this option too.